# Как (и возможно ли вообще) преобразовать даты из строки

Tags: php

Такая вот, на мой взгляд, интересная задачка. Есть текст, например:

> добрый день! ищу гида с испанским на 24-25.06, не круиз. 24.06 - вторая половина дня, эрмитаж, оплата 4000. 25.06 1 день с петергофом, оплата 6000. гид найден, всем спасибо за отклик!
>
> ищем индивидуального гида на 13е,14е, 15е июля, язык португальский, 20 евро в час.
>   добрый день ! нужен 21.06 во второй половине дня португальский гид на 5 часов обзорка
>
> нужен польский гид 10 июня с 17:00 до 19:00 на теплоход

Как все даты которые в нем встречаются, преобразовать в `date('Y-m-d')` ?

Comment: вы составьте все возможные варианты написания дат (хотя вряд ли у вас это получится) а потом принимайтесь за регулярные выражения

Comment: @teran в принципе , все возможные варианты я привел в вопросе)

Comment: как мне кажется это похоже на какие то произвольные пользовательские сообщения, так что возможных вариантов будет огромное множество, например `30.01-1.02`, год вы собираетесь брать текущий? а как насчет сообщения в декабре про `31.12-03.01 ` ? или `13-е` через дефис? или вместо `августа` будет написано `агуста?` Или человек не уверен, и напишет `ищем на 10е или 11 января`.

Answer (score 1):

Даты типа 24-25.06 24.06, в принципе, можно парсить через регулярные выражения (regular expression гугли). 13е, 14е, 15е июля будет проблематично, но, в принципе, так же можно регулярными выражениями разделить на день и месяц, а месяц из букв превращать в число через switch case. Автоматического метода обработки таких дат не знаю, но возможно есть библиотека на пхп, которая тебе поможет.

Comment: Хотелось бы какие-то примеры с кодами)

Comment: @Денис так-то некоторые из дат можно преобразовать через встроенную в пыху функцию http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date-parse-from-format.php а остальное рег.выражениями, код не дам, так как на пыхе давно не писал